# Centering ean13isbn barcode

Tags: barcodes

I am kindly requesting for assistance on how to center the `ean13isbn` barcode. I have tried using `\centering` or `\begin{center}...\end{center}` but the barcode still remains aligned to the left margin. Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[ISBN=978-80-85955-35-4,SC0]{ean13isbn}
\begin{document}
    \EANisbn[SC3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For unclear reasons, `\EANisbn` eventually does `\vbox{...}` and this is the cause of your problem: if `\EANisbn` appears between paragraphs it doesn't start one and the box is placed flush left whatever you try.

Add `\leavevmode` in front of `\EANisbn` or do

```
\mbox{\EANisbn{...}}
```

If you need the command several times, it makes sense to patch the relevant part so as to include `\leavevmode`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[ISBN=978-80-85955-35-4,SC0]{ean13isbn}

\AddToHook{cmd/EANbox/before}{\leavevmode}

\begin{document}

Start a paragraph

\EANisbn[SC3] is not flush left, but aligned with the indentation above

\begin{center}
\EANisbn[SC3]
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have an older (before October 2021) release of LaTeX, you can do the same job with `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and

```
\pretocmd{\EANbox}{\leavevmode}
```

instead of the `\AddToHook` line.